# VBA: Fill input in Web-based Outlook

Tags: html, vba, outlook-web-app

Fill input "To" "Cc" "Subject" "Message" in Web-based Outlook

The url of the OWA is "https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?version=2020051702.05&popoutv2=1&leanbootstrap=1"

The tag of the "Input" for "To" (as an example) is `<input autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-label="To" class="ms-BasePicker-input pickerInput_8d9d7e4e" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="combobox" data-lpignore="true" value="" tabindex="0">`

How should I write my VBA to assign an email address to OWA value part?

My code is as follows:

```
        Dim objIE As Object, i As Long, html As Object

        'Creare Internet Explorer
        Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With objIE
            .Visible = True 'true
            .Silent = True
            .Navigate "https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?version=2020051702.05&popoutv2=1&leanbootstrap=1"
            While .Busy = True Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set html = .Document
            html.querySelector("input[aria-label='To']").value = "XXX@email.com"
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something called CDO Check code below to set the email and email using CDO. 
It does not depend on MAPI or CDO and hence is dialog free and does not use your mail program to send emai.

Why using CDO code instead of Outlook automation or SendMail in VBA?

1. It doesn't matter what Mail program you are using (It only use the SMTP server).
2. It doesn't matter what Office version you are using (97…2016)
3. You can send a range/sheet in the body of the mail (some mail programs can’t do this)
4. You can send any file you like (Word, PDF, PowerPoint, TXT files,….)
5. No Security warnings, really great if you are sending a lot of mail in a loop.

you can find more information [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm)

```
 Sub SendMessage(Subject As String, Recipient As String, Body As String, User As String, Password As String)
   Dim sReq As String
   Dim xmlMethod As String
   Dim XMLreq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
   Dim EWSEndPoint As String
   EWSEndPoint = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
   sReq = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:t=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"">" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<soap:Header>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:RequestServerVersion Version=""Exchange2010""/>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</soap:Header>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<soap:Body>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<CreateItem MessageDisposition=""SendAndSaveCopy"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"">" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<SavedItemFolderId>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id=""sentitems"" />" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</SavedItemFolderId>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<Items>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:Message>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:Subject>" & Subject & "</t:Subject>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:Body BodyType=""Text"">" & Body & "</t:Body>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:ToRecipients>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "  <t:Mailbox>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "       <t:EmailAddress>" & Recipient & "</t:EmailAddress>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "  </t:Mailbox>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</t:ToRecipients>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</t:Message>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</Items>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</CreateItem>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</soap:Body>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</soap:Envelope>" & vbCrLf
   xmlMethod = "POST"
   XMLreq.Open xmlMethod, EWSEndPoint, False, User, Password
   XMLreq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
   XMLreq.setRequestHeader "Translate", "F"
   XMLreq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Blah"
   XMLreq.send sReq
   If XMLreq.Status = 207 Then
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the comment. But the receiver of the email depending on the result of the VBA program and also, before the email is sent out, the user would have to check the content so filling the OWA would be best. I looked into CDO also, but it seems like it is a method of sending email underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Helo, in my previous answer I did a workaround, haha sorry, You can use the following code to fill input on web form using `ie.document.getElementById("name").Value = objItem.SenderName`

```
Sub HelpdeskNewTicket()
Dim helpdeskaddress As String
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String
Dim oldmsg As String
Dim senderaddress As String
Dim addresstype As Integer
Dim ie         As Object
Dim sResult    As String
Dim dtTimer    As Date
Dim lAddTime   As Long


Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()


' Sender E=mail Address
senderaddress = objItem.SenderEmailAddress

'Searches for @ in the email address to determine if it is an exchange user
addresstype = InStr(senderaddress, "@")

' If the address is an Exchange DN use the Senders Name
If addresstype = 0 Then
senderaddress = objItem.SenderName
End If


   Const sOVIDURL As String = "http://helpdesk.com/admin"
   Const lREADYSTATE_COMPLETE As Long = 4

      Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      ie.Visible = True
      ie.navigate sOVIDURL

      dtTimer = Now
      lAddTime = TimeValue("00:00:20")

      Do Until ie.readystate = lREADYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not ie.busy
      DoEvents
      If dtTimer + lAddTime > Now Then Exit Do
      Loop

      ie.document.getElementById("user").Value = "yourusername"
      ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = "yourpassword"
      ie.document.forms(0).submit

      Do Until ie.readystate = lREADYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not ie.busy
      DoEvents
      If dtTimer + lAddTime > Now Then Exit Do
      Loop

      ie.navigate "http://helpdesk.com/admin/new_ticket.php"

      Do Until ie.readystate = lREADYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not ie.busy
      DoEvents
      If dtTimer + lAddTime > Now Then Exit Do
      Loop

               While ie.busy
            DoEvents
         Wend

      ie.document.getElementById("name").Value = objItem.SenderName
      ie.document.getElementById("subject").Value = objItem.Subject
      ie.document.getElementById("message").Value = objItem.Body
      dtTimer = Now
      lAddTime = TimeValue("00:00:20")
   Set ie = Nothing ' If you want to close it.


'Dim PageNumber As Object


Set objItem = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Set objApp = Application
On Error Resume Next
Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
Case "Explorer"
Set GetCurrentItem = _
objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Case "Inspector"
Set GetCurrentItem = _
objApp.ActiveInspector.currentItem
Case Else
End Select
End Function
```